stone Weierstrass theorem and null integrals
Let $g: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function,
such that $$\int_a^b\,g(x)\,dx=0.$$
Prove that there exists a suite of polynomes $\{P_n\}$, such that
$$
\int_a^b P_n(x)\,dx=0.
$$

According to the theorem of Stone-Weierstrass: if $g$ is continues on a closed interval $[a,b]$, then there exists a suite of polynomes $\{Q_n\}$, such that $\{Q_n\}$ converges uniformly to $g$.
Thus, according to theorem of interversion of limits and integrals:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_a^b Q_n(t)dt =\int_a^b\lim_{n \to \infty} Q_n(t)dt=\int_a^b g(x)dx=0.
$$

Problem:
I cannot figure how I am supposed to derive a suite of polynomes $\{P_n\}$ from $\{Q_n\}$ where $\int_a^b P_n(x)\,dx=0$.

Discussion:

In one of the online corrections they posed:
$$ P_n(t)=Q_n(t)-\int_a^b Q_n(t)dt$$
The only problem with that is when I calculate:
$$
\int_a^b P_n(x)dx = \int_a^b \left[Q_n(t)-\int_a^bQ_n(t)dt\right]= \alpha_2 x^2 - \alpha_{n+1} x^{n+1}\neq 0
$$
P. S. I do have to mention though that the form $Q_n(t)-\int_a^bQ_n(t) \,dt$ reminds me of integration by parts where $Q_n(t)$ is the integral of a function $v$, but I cannot seem to think of an efficient way to turn $Q_n(t)$ into a product.

In another correction the have posed:
$$P_n(t)=Q_n(t)-\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bQ_n(t)dt,$$ where the second term is the average value of $Q$.


Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

What I don't like about your referring to Weierstrass theorem is that you treat the polynomes as a sequence, but the theorem states it's just a polynome $P$, never even defining a degree of that polynome.

Try integrating the second one, it will work out

@EgorLarionov this question was part of a long problem. In the initial questions of the problem, this "version" of stone Weierstrass was demonstrated with the help of Heine and Bolzano Weierstrass theorem.

@balddraz ok so here is what I found. let Q_n(t)=a0+a1.t+ a2.t^2+....+an.t^n. thus integral of Q_n(t) from a to be is: a0(b-a)+....+an/(n+1).(b-a)^n+1. and the integral of  1/b-a * integral Qn(t)=t[a0+...+(an/(n+1))(b-a)^n.....basically the integral of Qn is a constant number thus its double integral will be that constant multiplied by t which is why I cannot understand how would that work. I seriously feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

@balddraz so I redid the calculations and I can't believe I completely forgot that the "t" will actually have to turn into b-a which is why the second formula works. thank you
